# How to select and item by deafult on page load, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a  jquery slider with animation that selecting pictures, How can I make an image in this slider to be "clicked" or "selected" by default on page load?
I need it because when the item is clicked another information appears, I need this information to appear by default on page load.

```
  carousel.on('itemSelected.sc', onItemClick);

   }



function onItemClick (evt) {
    var selected = $('.sc-selected'),
        title = selected.attr('data-title'),
        desc = selected.attr('data-desc'),
        srcLarge = selected.attr('data-src-large'),
        srcSmall = selected.attr('data-src-small');

    $('#image-src').attr('src', srcLarge);
       $('#image-src-small').attr('src', srcSmall);
    $('#item-title').html(title);
      $('#item-desc').html(desc);


}

$(window).on('load', initCarousel);

  }(jQuery.noConflict()));

 var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

the html (combined with Advanced custome fields, wordpress)

```
if( have_rows('carousel_images') ):

 while ( have_rows('carousel_images') ) : the_row(); 
    $image= get_sub_field('image_carousel1'); 
   $title= get_sub_field('image_carousel_title'); 
   $des=get_sub_field('image_carousel_discription'); 
   $largeimage=get_sub_field('large_image'); 
   $smallimage=get_sub_field('small_image'); 

   if( !empty($image)&&!empty($title)&&!empty($des)&&!empty($largeimage)&&!empty($smallimage) ):
        // thumbnail
        $thumb = $image;
        $title1= $title;
        $des1= $des;
        $largeimage1= $largeimage;
        $smallimage2= $smallimage;

    ?>

   <li class="carousel-item-container" data-title="<?php echo $title1 ?>" data-desc="<?php echo $des1 ?>" data-src-large="<?php echo $largeimage1 ?>" data-src-small="<?php echo  $smallimage2 ?>"> 

<img src="<?php echo $thumb ?>" class="carousel-item-image roller-gallery1" id="122">    </li>

      <?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Please also post the relevant HTML and CSS so we can replicate your issue and provide you with a working solution.

Comment: added the html.

Comment: And the relevant CSS please.

Comment: there is no relevant css to this

Comment: You could simply use  `.on('load',...)` and trigger a click on the Item you want with `.trigger('click')`

Comment: There sure is seeing that your `onItemClick()` function refers to two CSS classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the action manually. Put this inside the on load function.

```
$( "#element-to-be-clicked" ).trigger( "click" );
```